# Java Sockets + socket.io-client (Angular 13) = Failed connections and scrambled messages

Tags: java, angular, sockets

I am trying to use a Java Socket Server with `socket.io-client`, but it has an erratic behavior from the moment of the connection. It manages to stablish connection, but then this exception is thrown in Angular:

```
GET https://127.0.0.1:1532/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N__rEfS net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And the Server in Java only receives scrambled text repatedly
[image]

and the Client starts connecting and disconnecting over and over again. Why is this happening? Is there any way to get a cleaner Socket connection from Angular 13 to Java?

I use this Java Socket Server for many other applications and it works perfectly for everything else but this.

This is the routine that reads the Java Server:

```
void handleClientRequest() {
    try{
        mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));
        mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

        //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
        while (clientRun) {

            String clientMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

            if (clientMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {

                mMessageListener.messageReceived(clientMessage);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.printf("%s: Unexpected client disconnection. Reason:%n", accountId);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the Angular code:

```
this.socket = io('https://127.0.0.1:1532');

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  const engine = this.socket.io.engine;
  console.log(engine.transport.name); // in most cases, prints "polling"

  engine.once('upgrade', () => {
    // called when the transport is upgraded (i.e. from HTTP long-polling to WebSocket)
    console.log(engine.transport.name); // in most cases, prints "websocket"
  });

  engine.on('packet', ({  }) => {
    // called for each packet received
  });

  engine.on('packetCreate', ({  }) => {
    // called for each packet sent
  });

  engine.on('drain', () => {
    // called when the write buffer is drained
  });

  engine.on('close', (reason: any) => {
    // called when the underlying connection is closed
  });
});
```

Code taken from https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket IO is a communication protocol implemented on the top of websocket
from my understanding (correct me if im wrong) you are using raw socket in java.

So very likely that "scrambled" text that you are receiving, is part of https handshake.

My suggestion as way forward, will be to use library that handles websocket connections.

Comment: Yes, in Java I am using raw Sockets. I thought Socket IO was a simple Socket connectionb. But, I cannot use WebSocket in Java. Is there any way to get simple Sockets from Angular?

Comment: i dont think you can open raw tcp connection from browser, so you will need to use websocket library for java. is it any reason why you cant? what are your exact constrains and goal

Comment: I am using OSGi and under this environment the Jetty WebSocket Library I am using has some bugs which does not allow the WebSocket Server to receive connections. However, using a standalone application, the Jetty WebSockets work properly.

Comment: @JoeAlmore if you feel brave, you can implement own websocket server, there are many implementations floating on internet that you can borrow, ie this one
https://medium.com/@irunika/how-to-write-a-http-websocket-server-using-netty-f3c136adcba9